# Filter Json based on nested value

Tags: python, json

I have been struggling with filtering a json file and tried multiple solutions to no success.

My json looks like this :

```
{
  "some site": {
    "https://url.com/123...": {
      "Product Name": "A",
      "Product Price": "1213",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "Not Available"
    },
    "https://url.com/456...": {
      "Product Name": "B",
      "Product Price": "59.95",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  },
  "some other site": {
    "https://other_url.com/904543...": {
      "Product Name": "C",
      "Product Price": "479.95",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "Not Available"
    },
    "https://other_url.com/432489...": {
      "Product Name": "D",
      "Product Price": "5",
      "Product Category": "B",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  }
}
```

And I would like to filter the entire structure based on the key Product Availability == "In Stock" with an expected result of :

```
{
  "some site": {
    "https://url.com/456...": {
      "Product Name": "B",
      "Product Price": "59.95",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  },
  "some other site": {
    "https://other_url.com/432489...": {
      "Product Name": "D",
      "Product Price": "5",
      "Product Category": "B",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  }
}
```

I am reading the file using json_load():

```
def read_json(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file)
```

Minimal reproducible example :

```
import json

data = """
{
  "some site": {
    "https://url.com/123...": {
      "Product Name": "A",
      "Product Price": "1213",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "Not Available"
    },
    "https://url.com/456...": {
      "Product Name": "B",
      "Product Price": "59.95",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  },
  "some other site": {
    "https://other_url.com/904543...": {
      "Product Name": "C",
      "Product Price": "479.95",
      "Product Category": "A",
      "Product Availability": "Not Available"
    },
    "https://other_url.com/432489...": {
      "Product Name": "D",
      "Product Price": "5",
      "Product Category": "B",
      "Product Availability": "In Stock"
    }
  }
}"""

products = json.loads(data)

output_dict = [x for x,(z) in products.items() if z["Product Availability"] == "In Stock"]
print(output_dict)
```

Returns `KeyError: 'Product Availability'`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit a [mre] of the code of your honest attempt to to solve this into your question, and explain what’s wrong with the output. Suggest you avoid using list/dictionary comprehensions as they are so difficult to debug - just write for loops. Anyone should be able to copy/paste your code into a file and run it _without adding anything_ to see the result you put into the question. You need to include imports and data initializations otherise that isn’t possible.

Comment: Thanks @barny I have added a minimal reproducible example. I have also attempted to solve this with for loops with no success.

Comment: Compehensions won’t make it easier for you to solve or debug in order to solve. Write that for loop. Debug that for loop. Once you’ve got it working, maybe if you need fewer lines of code then cos\nsider using compehensions. But if for loops work well enough then why bother rewriting, because your time is much better spent solving real problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary, not a list comprehension.

`Product Availablity` is a key of the dicts nested inside `z`, not a key of `z` itself. You need a nested dict comprehension to filter the products in each site.

```
output_dict = {site: {
    url: attributes for url, attributes in p.items() if attributes['Product Availability'] == "In Stock"
    } for site, p in products.items()}
```

This can be written more understandably using regular nested loops.

```
output_dict = {}
for site, product_dict in products.items():
    output_site = {}
    for url, attributes in product_dict.items():
        if attributes['Product Availability'] == 'In Stock':
            output_site[url] = attributes
    output_dict[site] = output_site
```

Comment: The OP needs an understandable and debuggable piece of code - for a relative beginner in Python comprehensions don’t fit that requirement.

Comment: Much better, thanks for adding the for loop version.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar this is a much more readable answer. Indent broken starting line 2 but aside from that I can actually read and understand the code. Much appreciated!
I will in the future research dictionary comprehensions to get a better understanding of what seems like a very powerful tool!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a nested dict comprehension, but it's not exactly easy to understand at the first glance:

```
{key: {s: v for s, v in val.items() if v.get("Product Availability") == "In Stock"} for key, val in data.items()}
```

which gives:

```
{
    "some site": {
        "https://url.com/456...": {
            "Product Name": "B",
            "Product Price": "59.95",
            "Product Category": "A",
            "Product Availability": "In Stock"
        }
    },
    "some other site": {
        "https://other_url.com/432489...": {
            "Product Name": "D",
            "Product Price": "5",
            "Product Category": "B",
            "Product Availability": "In Stock"
        }
    }
}
```

...but realistically, it might be more manageable to use a nested loop:

```
import json

site_data = json.reads('your JSON...')
result = {}

for site_title, urls in site_data.items():
    result[site_title] = {}
    for url, url_data in urls.items():
        if site_data.get("Product Availability") == "In Stock":
            result[site_title][url] = url_data
```

The result is the same.

Comment: The OP needs an understandable and debuggable piece of code - for a relative beginner in Python comprehensions don’t fit that requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak, I got the expected result by modifying data.items to products.items.
I'm not sure I would feel comfortable using the code as-is though given how, as you said, it doesn't read naturally for a newbie like me :)

Comment: @Thiousi I've added a more explicit version :)